# Is it considered bad convention when in iterating through two maps, I don't check if key exists in one of them?

Tags: kotlin

I have two maps, let's call them `oneMap` and `twoMap`.

I am iterating through all the keys in `oneMap`, and if the key exists in `twoMap` I do something
like

```
fun exampleFunc(oneMap: Map<String, Any>, twoMap: Map<String, Any>) {
   for((oneMapKey, oneMapVal) in oneMap) {
      if (twoMap.containsKey(oneMapKey)) {
         val twoMapVal = twoMap[oneMapKey]
         if (twoMapVal == oneMapVal) {
            //do more stuff
         }  
         //do more stuff, I have more if statements
      }      
   }
}
```

To avoid having more nested if statements, I was wondering if instead I could get rid of the

`if (twoMap.containsKey(oneMapKey))` check. if `twoMap` doesn't contain the `oneMapKey`, we get a null object, and my code still works fine. I was wondering if this is considered bad convention though

```
fun exampleFunc(oneMap: Map<String, Any>, twoMap: Map<String, Any>) {
   for((oneMapKey, oneMapVal) in oneMap) {
      
      val twoMapVal = twoMap[oneMapKey]
      if (twoMapVal == oneMapVal) {
         //do more stuff
      }  
      //do more stuff, I have more if statements
        
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any issues with your second way of doing it. The `containsKey` check could be relevant if your value type of the first map were nullable, which isn't the case with the code you posted.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. Do you wanna execute the "more stuff" or not?

If you do not wanna execute it you should keep the if condition. Though, if you are concerned about indentation (and deep if hierarchies) you can consider breaking out of the loop:

```kotlin
for((oneMapKey, oneMapVal) in oneMap) {
  if (!twoMap.contains(oneMapKey)) continue // continue with next iteration

  // do more stuff
}
```

If your map does not contain null values you can also get the value and check if the result was null (which means the key was not present in the map):

```kotlin
for((oneMapKey, oneMapVal) in oneMap) {
  val twoMapVal: Any = twoMap[oneMapKey] ?: continue // continue with next iteration

  // do more stuff
}
```

So its always good practice the remove useless code and (in my opinion) to have less if-hierarchies, as you can easily loose focus when you have lots of nested conditions.

Answer (score 0):

As Tenfour04 says, omitting the `containsKey()` check is only an option if the map values aren't nullable; if they are, then `[]`/`get()` gives no way to distinguish between a missing mapping and a mapping to a null value.

But if not (or if you want to ignore null values anyway), then I'd certainly consider omitting the check; the resulting code would be slightly shorter and slightly more efficient, without losing clarity or maintainability.  It could also avoid [a potential race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use).  (Though in a multi-threaded situation, I'd be considering more robust protection!)

One variation is to use `let()` along with the safe-call `?.` operator to restrict it to non-null cases:

```
for ((oneMapKey, oneMapVal) in oneMap) {
    twoMap[oneMapKey]?.let { twoMapVal ->
        if (twoMapVal == oneMapVal) {
            // Do more stuff
        }
        // Do more stuff
    }
}
```

Using `?.let()` this way seems to be a fairly common idiom in Kotlin, so it should be fairly transparent.